# Why this in onDeviceReady is not this as usual?

Tags: javascript, cordova

Below code is from index.js generated by PhoneGap 3.0, my question is why it was not designed to allow us to use this.receivedEvent as usual (and get event object as a parameter).

```
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
   app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Its the usual call:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use device APIs
}
```

Refer the official site: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready

Comment: I know this, my question was in context of index.js, where PhoneGap tell me to call app.receivedEvent instead of this.receivedEvent, thanks.